# Regular Expression with vb.net, and PStools

Tags: regex, vb.net

Im using VB.net and PStools to create a simple progam for work so we can see if one person is logged onto more than one PC.

when I run the code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("psloggedon")
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc.Start()

    TextBox2.Text = Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd

    Proc.Close()
End Sub
```

I get the results:

```
"Users logged on locally:
     1/1/2014 4:14:43 PM        Joseph_Garza\Joseph.Garza

No one is logged on via resource shares."
```

However, where it says "Joseph_Garza" its going to say my companies name.

so.. Company_name\Joseph.Garza

How can I use regular expressions to get:

```
1.the time and date  
2.Joseph.Garza
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

Regex.Match Method (String) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex maybe?

```
Users logged on locally:\s*((?:(?!\s{2,}).)*)\s*([^\\]*)\\(\S+)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qT8aN8)

`Users logged on locally:` matches literally.

`\s*` matches 0 or more spaces, tabs and newlines.

`((?:(?!\s{2,}).)*)` The outermost parens here are used to store the capture. The inner part is a pattern to match every character except two or more spaces in a row. `(?!\s{2,})` is what prevents the matching of more than 2 spaces and is making use of a negative lookahead `(?! ... )`. `{2,}` means `\s` is being repeated at least twice. `.` is a wildcard which matches all characters except newlines.

`([^\\]*)` The outermost parens are used to store the second part. The inner part is a pattern to match every character except backslashes `\`. `[^ ... ]` is a negated class and will match everything *not* inside it.

`\\` matches a single backslash and...

`(\S+)` is used to match non-spaces, non-newlines, non-tab characters and store the match.

And implementing it in VB:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Example
   Public Sub Main()
      Dim pattern As String = "Users logged on locally:\s*((?:(?!\s{2,}).)*)\s*([^\\]*)\\(\S+)" 
      Dim input As String = "Users logged on locally:" & vbCrlf & _
                            "     1/1/2014 4:14:43 PM        Joseph_Garza\Joseph.Garza" & vbCrlf & _
                            "No one is logged on via resource shares."
      Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
      If match.Success Then
         For ctr As Integer = 1 To match.Groups.Count - 1
            Dim captureCtr As Integer = 0
            For Each capture As Capture In match.Groups(ctr).Captures
               Console.WriteLine("Matches: {1}", _
                                 captureCtr, capture.Value)
               captureCtr += 1                  
            Next 
         Next 
      End If    
   End Sub 
End Module
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/Bq5LnD)

NOTE: I just added the company name, just in case, but if you absolutely don't need it, just use this [regex](http://regex101.com/r/cC9wD8):

```
Users logged on locally:\s*((?:(?!\s{2,}).)*)\s*[^\\]*\\(\S+)
```

(The brackets around the `[^\\]*` was removed)